# PHP paging on dynamic page does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to get paging on my dynamic page.
I am using PDO in my script. The paging script I whant to include was with mysql and not with PDO so I changed the mysql functions to PDO functions. But my problem is that the script with mysql works and the scripts with pdo not. If I click next page or page 2 in the script with PDO I get all the first 10 records as well and I can't go to the previous page. And in my mysql script it works all fine!

I have searched on Stackoverflow and the internet for a solution but I can't find one, so does somebody know what I am doing wrong? Or how I could fix this?

I have error handling enabled. And the only error message I get from the script with PDO is:

`Notice: Undefined index: page on line 22`

But when I click on next I don't get this error message anymore.

My scripts with PDO:

```
<?php
    include('php/loginHandlerconnect.php'); 

    $db = loginHandlerconnect();

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $tableName="vacature";      
    $targetpage = "testpaging3.php";
    $limit = 10; 

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(vacatureID) AS num FROM $tableName";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total_pages = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
    var_dump($total_pages); // output: string(2) "11" > after clicking on next: string(2) "11" string(1) "2"

    $stages = 3;
    var_dump($_GET['page']); // output: NULL
    $page = (isset($_GET['page']));
    if($page){
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
    }else{
        $start = 0; 
    }   

    // Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT vacature.*, werkgever.image, werkgever.plaats, werkgever.provincie, werkgever.naamBedrijf FROM vacature LEFT JOIN werkgever ON (vacature.werkgeverID = werkgever.werkgeverID) ORDER BY vacature.datum DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = $db->prepare($query1);
    $result->execute();
    $results = $result->fetchAll();

    // Initial page num setup
    if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
    $prev = $page - 1;  
    $next = $page + 1;                          
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    


    $paginate = '';
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
        // Previous
        if ($page > 1){
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }

        // Pages    
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
        {
            // Beginning only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // Middle hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // End only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
            }
        }

                // Next
        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
            }

        $paginate.= "</div>";       


}
 echo $total_pages.' Results'; // output: 11 Results



        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['datum'])); 
            echo "
                <div class='vacatureinfo2'> 
                    <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $row['image'] ."' id='imge'/> 
                    <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $row['functie'] ." - ". $row['naamBedrijf'] ." - ". $row['plaats'] ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $date ."</p> 
                    <div class='omschrijvingkort2'> 
                        ". $row['omschrijvingKort'] ." 
                    </div> 
                    <p class='pull-right'><a href='reactie?id=" . $row['vacatureID'] . "'>Reageer</a> | <a href='informatie-vacature?id=" . $row['vacatureID'] . "'>Meer informatie</a></p> 
                </div> 
                <hr>";
        }
 // pagination
 echo $paginate; // output: previous12next (previous and 1 are not working after clicking on next or 2)
?>
```

My script with mysql:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php'); 

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $tableName="vacature";      
    $targetpage = "testpaging2.php";    
    $limit = 10; 

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(vacatureID) as num FROM $tableName";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
    var_dump($total_pages); // output: string(2) "11" > after clicking on next: string(2) "11" string(1) "2"

    $stages = 3;
    var_dump($_GET['page']); // output: NULL
    $page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);
    if($page){
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
    }else{
        $start = 0; 
    }   

    // Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT vacature.*, werkgever.image, werkgever.plaats, werkgever.provincie, werkgever.naamBedrijf FROM vacature LEFT JOIN werkgever ON (vacature.werkgeverID = werkgever.werkgeverID) ORDER BY vacature.datum DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);

    // Initial page num setup
    if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
    $prev = $page - 1;  
    $next = $page + 1;                          
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    


    $paginate = '';
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
        // Previous
        if ($page > 1){
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }

        // Pages    
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page){
                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                }else{
                    $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
        {
            // Beginning only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // Middle hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
                $paginate.= "...";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            // End only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                $paginate.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page){
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    }else{
                        $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
                }
            }
        }

                // Next
        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
        }else{
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
            }

        $paginate.= "</div>";       


}
 echo $total_pages.' Results'; // output: 11 Results



        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['datum'])); 
        echo "
            <div class='vacatureinfo2'> 
                <img class='userimg2' src='../../uploads/userimage/". $row['image'] ."' id='imge'/> 
                <p class='func-br-pl pull-left'>". $row['functie'] ." - ". $row['naamBedrijf'] ." - ". $row['plaats'] ."</p><p class='dtm pull-right'>". $date ."</p> 
                <div class='omschrijvingkort2'> 
                    ". $row['omschrijvingKort'] ." 
                </div> 
                <p class='pull-right'><a href='reactie?id=" . $row['vacatureID'] . "'>Reageer</a> | <a href='informatie-vacature?id=" . $row['vacatureID'] . "'>Meer informatie</a></p> 
            </div> 
            <hr>";

        }
 // pagination
 echo $paginate; // output: previous12next (previous and 1 are working after clicking on next or 2)
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of questions is off topic for this site.

Comment: @YourCommonSense why is it off topic?? It's a normal question!!

Comment: which line is the line 22, where its showing the error????

Comment: @ManojSalvi the line on line 22 is: `var_dump($_GET['page']);` and if I comment it the notice is gone

Comment: well than check if you have ?page=[somepageno.like3,4,5...] at the end of your url....

Comment: @ManojSalvi at first I don't get ?page=1 at the end of my url but after clicking on next (from paging) I get ?page=2 but than I can't click on previous or 1... and he show all the first records again on ?page=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']));
```

To the following:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

Than the script works!

Comment: More like `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;`

Comment: Thanks that works as well!

Answer (score 2):

I would be extremely suprised if this questions has not been answered dozens of times just here in SO.

First of all, this is not an error, this is a notice only. It means that there is no 'page' element in the $_GET array, but you wanted to access it in the var_dump($_GET['page']) function call.

Since this line is there for debugging purposes only, you can safely comment it out. If you load the page for the first time, then the page parameter would not be set, so it is not a surprise that it does not exist.

You should check for its existence though with isset() before attempting to use it in the following line.

Comment: thanks for your aswer! But I have found the solution :) (see answer above)